# Why are data records introduced by a module removed when I update that module in Odoo 10?

Tags: xml, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I have just restored a database in Odoo 10. I have even copied the source code of the instance and the virtualenv from the server to preserve the environment. The restoration worked OK, I can work with the database.

But I want to update all the modules, and I get some critical errors when updating some of them. For example, when I try to update only one module (`l10n_es`), I get this error:

> odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_model: Deleting 24@account.account.type (l10n_es.account_type_ingresos_neto)
> odoo.sql_db: bad query: DELETE FROM account_account_type WHERE id IN
> (24) ...
> NotNullViolation: null value in column "user_type_id" violates
> not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (712, null, other,
> Beneficios en activos financieros disponibles para la venta, 1, f, 1,
> 1, null, 900000000, 2018-02-01 09:28:54.453977, null, 2018-02-01
> 09:28:54.453977, null, f). CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE ONLY
> "public"."account_account" SET "user_type_id" = NULL WHERE $1
> OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "user_type_id""

Before doing the update, I made the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM ir_model_data WHERE model='account.account.type' AND res_id=24;
```

Which returns the following:

```
  id  | create_uid |        create_date         |         write_date         | write_uid | noupdate |            name            |      date_init      |     date_update     | module  |        model         | res_id 
------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------+--------
 7850 |          1 | 2018-02-01 09:19:01.412377 | 2021-02-08 15:28:04.013464 |         1 | f        | account_type_ingresos_neto | 2018-02-01 09:19:01 | 2021-02-08 15:28:04 | l10n_es | account.account.type |     24
```

And then I execute this:

```
SELECT * FROM account_account_type WHERE id=24;
```

Which returns:

```
 id | create_uid |           name           | write_uid | note |         write_date         |        create_date         | include_initial_balance | type  
----+------------+--------------------------+-----------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+-------
 24 |          1 | Ingresos patrimonio neto |         1 |      | 2021-02-08 15:28:04.013464 | 2018-02-01 09:19:01.412377 | t                       | other
```

With these two queries I confirmed that, in the database, there is an account type with ID 24 named *Ingresos patrimonio neto*, which has the *External XML ID* `l10n_es.account_type_ingresos_neto`.

If I check the code of the instance, the module `l10n_es` has a folder `data` where there is a file named `account_type.xml`. This file is called by the `__manifest__.py` and creates the record:

```
<record id="account_type_ingresos_neto" model="account.account.type">
    <field name="name">Ingresos patrimonio neto</field>
    <field name="include_initial_balance" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

So, I cannot understand why when I update the module, it removes this record (this fact produces the error):

```
odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_model: Deleting 24@account.account.type (l10n_es.account_type_ingresos_neto)
```

I thought that when a module was updated, it removed the records (introduced by it) whose *External XML ID* (in database) was not in the code anymore, as this answer explains: [Why is the account module upgrade unlinking records on some tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732572/why-is-the-account-module-upgrade-unlinking-records-on-some-tables/53738741#comment123451979_53738741)

Why is the module deleting the existing records with still existing *XML IDs* when I update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEFINITIVE ANSWER**

Finally I realized that I had the guilty module (`l10n_es`) repeated twice in the Odoo instance. It was in two different paths called by `addons_path` parameter.

In the case of `l10n_es` for version 10.0, Odoo Community Association has the module in two different repositories: `OCB` and `l10n-spain`. This is not the case of the later versions of Odoo, in which OCA uses OCB `l10n_es` and does not create its own `l10n_es`.

**OLD ANSWER**

The problem on changing the module or the name in the `ir_model_data` (the solution of the link referenced in the question) is that those records we change can be duplicated on module update.

My solution was to execute this query on the conflictive records:

```
UPDATE ir_model_data SET noupdate=TRUE WHERE module='l10n_es' AND name='account_type_ingresos_neto';
```

This way, the records are not deleted when updating the module and therefore, other records (which have them set as foreign key) do not raise a not null error.

In fact, I think that the module `l10n_es` should change the `<data>` tag to `<data noupdate="1">` in some XML files which load new records.

But actually, I don't know if this is the best solution.

Comment: I don't understand why Odoo is even trying to delete the record. If it's in the xml of the module/app why even trying to delete it. Or to point to the code in the other question: why is there no entry in `self.loads` (`_process_end()`)?

Comment: I have just found the real problem: the module *l10n_es* is twice in the addons path. There is one in the *OCA/OCB* repository and there is another one in *OCA/l10n-spain*. So that is the reason of these nosense. The stupid fact is that I knew this OCA issue but I had forgotten since it has been a long time from the last 10.0 installation I had done.

Comment: oh okay. double module entries can trigger some problems.